# Entity Framework 6 save changes in child collection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, orm

I have some trouble saving my entities. I'm using a mvc pattern for my wpf application and directly bind the entities to the user interface.

Now I have the following two classes:

```
public class Extension : DataModelBase
{
    private int _extensionId;
    private string _extensionName;
    private ExtensionGroup _extensionGroup;
    private int? _currentExtensionGroupId;

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ExtensionId
    {
        get
        {
            return _extensionId;
        }

        set
        {
            _extensionId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ExtensionName
    {
        get
        {
            return _extensionName;
        }

        set
        {
            _extensionName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ExtensionGroup ExtensionGroup
    {
        get { return _extensionGroup; }
        set
        {
            _extensionGroup = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int? CurrentExtensionGroupId
    {
        get { return _currentExtensionGroupId; }
        set
        {
            _currentExtensionGroupId = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class ExtensionGroup : DataModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    private ObservableCollection<Extension> _extensions = new ObservableCollection<Extension>();
    private int _extensionGroupId;

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ExtensionGroupId
    {
        get { return _extensionGroupId; }
        set
        {
            _extensionGroupId = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Extension> Extensions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_extensions == null)
            {
                _extensions = new ObservableCollection<Extension>();
            }
            return _extensions;
        }

        set
        {
            _extensions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Extensions));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see every ExtensionGroup contains n Extension. The user can add extensions to an extension group and if he saves the group I want EF to automaticly add the ExtensionGroup property in the class Extension.

Therefore I configured the following

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExtensionGroup>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Extensions)
            .WithOptional(x => x.ExtensionGroup)
            .HasForeignKey(x=>x.CurrentExtensionGroupId);

    }
```

So what is to do now? After 1 million trys I am really confused now :D
And I think it's a problem that I'd loaded these "this.Model.LoadedExtensionGroups" groups from another EF context...

```
using (var context = new FODataModel())
        {
            foreach (var extensionGroup in this.Model.LoadedExtensionGroups)
            {
                //What to do here?


                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

In my tries it came either to errors (for example InvalidOperationException for this:`context.Entry(extensionGroup).State = EntityState.Modified;`)
or he made duplicate entries [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emu4J.png).
I hope somebody can help.
Thank you!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @GertArnold "While the EF team has done a lot to make working with disconnected data easier from one version of EF to the next, it’s still a problem that daunts many developers who aren’t well-versed in the expected behavior of EF."

I still did not get it... :D i tried something out... can it be that it is a big overhead?

Comment: you'll have to find out which objects are updates and which ones are inserts. How you do that is pretty much irrelevant, EF has no option to make this decision other than the PK value.